# bash script on padding 0 on digit with character

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a bash scritpt where it will put 0 padding infront of a hexadecimal character eg. 32b, ae2, etc.   it works on just integer but not on mix character and digit.   I used

```
printf "%04d$a\n" .  a=ae2.
```

what I want to happen is like this  0ab3,   003s,  000a,  002a padding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
printf '%04x\n' "0x${a}"
```

`x` in format specification stands for hexadecimal integer (lowercase). And without `0x` prefix in argument bash will complain that `ae2` is an invalid number.

Comment: Cool :-) Nice mentioning about the `0x` prefix.